# How to Bind Tooltip's DataTemplate to its Parent?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, templatebinding

I Wrote the Codes below to Show the image in Content of the `ListBoxItem` in the Tooltip window (kind of Preview effect). but they are not working at all.

```xml
<ListBox>
  <ListBoxItem>
    <Image x:Name="image" Source="image.jpg" Stretch="Uniform">
      <Image.ToolTip>
        <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Image}, Path=Source}" />
      </Image.ToolTip>
    </Image>
  </ListBoxItem>  
<ListBox>
```

```xml
<ListBox>
  <ListBoxItem>
    <Image x:Name="image" Source="image.jpg" Stretch="Uniform">
      <Image.ToolTip>
        <Image Source="{Binding Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
      </Image.ToolTip>
    </Image>
  </ListBoxItem>  
<ListBox>
```

```xml
<ListBox>
  <ListBoxItem>
    <Image x:Name="image" Source="image.jpg" Stretch="Uniform">
      <Image.ToolTip>
        <Image Source="{Binding}" />
      </Image.ToolTip>
    </Image>
  </ListBoxItem>  
<ListBox>
```

None of these worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Image x:Name="image" Source="screen.png" Stretch="Uniform">
            <Image.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip>
                    <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}, Path=PlacementTarget.Source}" />
                </ToolTip>
            </Image.ToolTip>
        </Image>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

The `Image` is not a visual ancestor of a `ToolTip` but you could use the `ToolTip`'s `PlacementTarget` property to bind to the `Image`.